# Azure AD B2C - Original authentication source is missing after token refresh

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, microsoft-entra-id

I am currently working on an Azure AD B2C custom policy that enables users to have multiple identities (Google, Microsoft, Apple, and Entra ID). The Entra ID ClaimsProvider sets an **`entraTenantId`** claim derived from the **`iss`** claim, which is then sent to the application via RelyingParty.

However, I have noticed that after the application acquires a new token using **`grant_type: refresh_token`**, the UserJourney **`RedeemRefreshToken`** does not return the **`entraTenantId`** or **`identityProvider`**, which are crucial for my application's functionality.

Could someone please advise on how to ensure that the **`entraTenantId`** and **`identityProvider`** are included in the refreshed token or suggest alternative approaches to address this issue?

I attempted to address the issue by adding the **`entraTenantId`** output claim to the **`RefreshTokenReadAndSetup`** ClaimsProvider, but unfortunately, this adjustment did not yield the expected outcome.

My objective is to retrieve and output the name of the provider that the user originally used to sign in from the **`RedeemRefreshToken`** journey.

The solution I am pursuing is based on the [SocialAndLocalAccounts](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/tree/main/SocialAndLocalAccounts) example provided by Azure AD B2C.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else is having the same issue, I finally got it working by just adding the claims to `RefreshTokenReadAndSetup` TechnicalProfile. There is no clear mention in the docs, but AAD B2C is able to use the original authetication context when issuing the new token.

```
  <ClaimsProvider>
    <DisplayName>Refresh token journey</DisplayName>
    <TechnicalProfiles>
      <TechnicalProfile Id="RefreshTokenReadAndSetup">
        <DisplayName>Trustframework Policy Engine Refresh Token Setup Technical Profile</DisplayName>
        <Protocol Name="None" />
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="refreshTokenIssuedOnDateTime" />
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="entraTenantId" PartnerClaimType="entra_id_tenant" />
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" />

        </OutputClaims>
      </TechnicalProfile>
```